# How to make CURL call from CMD line (Win 7) to MVC action with parameter?

Tags: api, rest, curl, yii2, updatemodel

I'm building the REST-full API with CRUD actions in Yii 2.0 and I need help for update action.

In my Yii 2.0 MVC controller I have actions create and update as follow:

```
public function actionCreate()
{
    ...
}
```

For create action I can make **CURL** calls successfully with the command:

```
curl -X POST -d column_one=create_test1 -d column_two=create_test2 http://localhost/MyApp/web/tabletest/create
```

And after this call, the new row in my table with the above values for columns is successfully created.

Now I need to make **CURL** calls for update action as well:

```
public function actionUpdate($id)
{
    ...
}
```

I have tried a lot of variations for this command (now we have parameter in the function and I'm not sure how to pass it - let's assumed that `$id=2`). These are only a few of the ones that I tried, ***none is working***:

```
curl -X PUT -d column_two=updated_cmd_2 http://localhost/MyApp/web/tabletest/update/2

curl -X PUT -d "column_two=updated_cmd_2" "http://localhost/MyApp/web/tabletest/update/2"

curl -X PUT -d "id=2&column_two=updated_cmd_2" "http://localhost/MyApp/web/tabletest/update"
```

But in most of the cases I got the error:

```
Bad Request (#400)
```

*NOTE: The create method is defined as POST method and update method is defined as PUT method, so the method type is not a problem in this case. ***I think that format of CURL call for update is not correct***.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem by replacing one of my custom actions in the controller:

```
public function beforeAction($action) 
{
    if($this->action->id == 'create'){
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

into:

```
public function beforeAction($action) 
{
    if($this->action->id == 'create' || $this->action->id == 'update'){
        $this->enableCsrfValidation = false;
    }

    return parent::beforeAction($action);
}
```

and now:

```
curl -X PUT -d column_two=updated_cmd_2 http://localhost/MyApp/web/tabletest/update/2
```

is working.